# Can somebody explain this short python method

Tags: python, class, methods

I am following an Python tutorial but do not understand this class.
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

Can somebody explain to me how the next_scene method works.
Why does it switch to the next scene?

```
class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

Comment: It doesn't switch to the *next* scene. It switches to the scene you specify in the arguments you pass to the function.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking here... What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It instantiates a scene object from the `scenes` dictionary depending on the keyword you pass to it, and returns it back to you.

> Why does it switch to the next scene?

The reason it switches to the next scene is because in the base class each scene extends specifies the next scene in the sequence after it finishes running through `enter()` function :

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()  # returns next scene key
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)  # initiates next scene and sets it as `current_scene`
```

For example the `CentralCorridor` scene at the end dependeding on the inputted action returns the next scence's key :

```
def enter(self):
    print "The Gothons of Planet Percal #25 have invaded your ship and destroyed"
    ...
    print "flowing around his hate filled body.  He's blocking the door to the"
    print "Armory and about to pull a weapon to blast you."

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "shoot!":
        print "Quick on the draw you yank out your blaster and fire it at the Gothon."
        ...
        print "you are dead.  Then he eats you."
        return 'death'  # next scene `Death`

    elif action == "dodge!":
        print "Like a world class boxer you dodge, weave, slip and slide right"
        ...
        print "your head and eats you."
        return 'death'  # next scene `Death`

    elif action == "tell a joke":
        print "Lucky for you they made you learn Gothon insults in the academy."
        ...
        return 'laser_weapon_armory'  # next scene `LaserWeaponArmory`

    else:
        print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
        return 'central_corridor'  # next scene `CentralCorridor`
```

And the whole sequence ends with the death scene's `enter()` function that exits the program :

```
def enter(self):
    print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks I did not notice that! That makes it a whole lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)`

`Map.scenes` is the dictionary defined in your class. Calling `.get()` on it gets the value of the key given. The key given in this case is `scene_name`. Then the function returns an instance of a scene.

It's similar to:

```
return scenes[scene_name]
```

Except instead of raising a KeyError if the key isn't there, `None` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `next_scene` you would pass a `scene_name` variable.

```
test_map = Map('central_corridor')
test_map.next_scene('the_bridge')
```

When passing it `the_bridge`, it checks the dictionary `scenes` in the class and tries to get your chosen scene from it.

The `get` method is used so a `KeyError` exception is not raised if you were to call the method with an invalid scene name (e.g. `test_map.next_scene('the_computer`)). In this case it would just return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The `next_scene` name is misleading.  It's not going to give the "next" scene from some intrinsic ordering, but rather it returns a scene that you choose, presumably the next one you want to choose.